# Aspect fails with ClassCastException trying to pointcut Tomcat DataSource getConnection

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop, tomcat8, tomcat-jdbc

I need to execute several initialization statements on each borrowed connection from a Tomcat JDBC Pool. I cannot use JDBCInterceptors because pool is shared with other applications that won't need said initilization.

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.4, deploying on Tomcat 8.5.11, which has a ResourceLink in context.xml to a Resource in server.xml that defines the DataSource against a Oracle 11g Database. I'm accessing the DataSource via JNDI.

As per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38746398 I wanted to use Spring AOP to accomplish my goal.

I have created and Aspect that works perfectly if the DataSource is defined directly in context.xml, but fails with a ClassCastException if referenced via a ResourceLink to the same definition in server.xml

The exception is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$26808f96.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$17f85659.getConnection(<generated>)
```

My Aspect class:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class DataSourceAspect {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataSourceAspect.class);

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection())")
    public void afterConnectionEstablished() {
        LOG.info("Borrowed connection from the pool. Initializing...");
    }
}
```

ResourceLink definition in context.xml:

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/us_j2eeCoreDS"
   global="jdbc/us_j2eeCoreDS"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

DataSource definition in server.xml (changed private values):

```
<Resource name="jdbc/us_j2eeCoreDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
         global="jdbc/us_j2eeCoreDS"
         factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
         driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
         username="xxx" password="xxx"
         initialSize="1"
         minIdle="1"
         maxIdle="4" maxWaitMillis="5000"
         maxActive="40"
         removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
         testWhileIdle="true"
         validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
         timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000"
         url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID"/>
```

As I said before, if I define the exact same DataSource in context.xml, it works flawlessly.

Any clue?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually the problem was not AOP related, but a dependency conflict.

The project is based on Spring Boot 1.4.4.RELEASE. In my `build.gradle`, I had the following dependency:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
```

Being a starter, it's just a quick way to get more needed dependencies. One of the deps provided is:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:1.4.4.RELEASE
```

Which provides:

```
org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:8.5.11
```

So as it turns out my war package ended up containing `tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar`.

Tomcat 8.5.11 server also contained the same library, `tomcat-jdbc.jar`.

As the pool was `server.xml` defined, the library used by the pool was `tomcat-jdbc.jar`, but my application, having `tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar` inside its `WEB-INF/libs` directory, used `tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar`, leading to the ClassCastException. I didn't have time to dig out more and find the actual reason why it worked if the pool was defined in `context.xml`, but I guess it's just a case of jar loading priority.

**The fix**: exclude the `tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar` from the war package, using the following gradle enchanment (just include it in your `build.gradle` configurations section):

```
configurations {
    runtime.exclude module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
}
```

Hope this helps somebody else!